# sum of digits of a number in base B

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algorithms, recreational-mathematics, computational-mathematics

We are given a number $n$ in base $10$, now we have to find the sum of the digits of this number if it was written in base $B$.
For example :
if $n=216$ and $B=2$

$$216=2^7+2^6+2^4+2^3$$
so $216$ in binary would look like $11011000,$
now the sum of the digits in this will come out to be $4.$

Is it possible to find a function $f(n, B)$ that can give out this answer? If yes then what will it be?

PS: the second part of the problem...
now we are given a number R.Find the value of B corresponding to which f(n, B) is minimum for all 2≤B≤R
as i have to use this in a program can someone find a function or maybe an approach to solve this such that it can be computed very quickly as the numbers n and r can have values ranging from 2 to 10^12

Comment: A nitpick.  "function" $\ne$ "formula".  Of course there is a function.  It is $f: n\mapsto \text{sum of the digits of }n$.  What you are really asking for is can we express this function as simple formula.... sorry for being pedandtic but.... well, the distinction will become *very* important later.

Comment: For the second part, take $B=n$ and $f(n,B)=1$

Comment: @RossMillikan But it is stated that $B≤R$. What if $n>R$? Maybe it would be possible to just verify for every $2\leq B\leq R$ in case $n>R$, but maybe there is a more clever way to do this second part.

Comment: You can optimize the code to consider only $B\leq \min(R, \sqrt n) $ or even $B\leq \min(R, n^{1/3})$. I'm too tired now to write an answer so here's two hints, you can find a small upper bound on the min of $f(n, B)$. Second hint is $\sqrt n$ is special.

Comment: @kingW3 thanks i will try it

Comment: Looks like you're looking for the hamming weight of the binary number. In other base it could be different tho.

Comment: @kingW3 ur answer seems the most legit , but i still dont understand it

Comment: I'm writing an answer, out of curiosity where is this problem from?

Comment: @kingW3 i just need it in programming

Comment: Yeah, I've assumed that I'm wondering if it's from some contest or online judge like SPOJ or something?

Comment: @kingW3 yeah why?

Comment: @kingW3 can i not ask those questions here? I'm new here so idk

Comment: I'm just wondering where it's from to understand how to write the answer, and as a contest programmer myself I always wonder how well I compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upper bound of the solution is $\lfloor \log_2(n)\rfloor +1$ because that's how many digits $n$ has in base $2$ (binary) and each of them is at most $1$. While programming you can just find $f(n, 2)$.

Now when $B>\lfloor \sqrt n \rfloor$ we have that $n$ has at most $2$ digits because $B^2>n$. Lets write a number in such base as $xB+y=n$ now we are wondering if we can find such $x, y$ such that $x+y<f(n, 2)$, lets rewrite $xB+y=n$ as $B=(n-y)/x$ now we iterate over $x+y=k$ where $1<k<f(n,2)$ and check if $B$ is an integer (smaller than $R$) , stop once you find such $B$ and $k$ is the minimum for $B>\lfloor \sqrt n \rfloor$.

Now you are left to find min of $f(n, B) $ where $B\leq\lfloor \sqrt n \rfloor$ which you can do by simply iterating.

Possible optimization is to repeat the process for $B>\lfloor n^{1/3} \rfloor$ just with $xB^2+yB+z=n$ here solving for $B$ it's marginally harder, anyway I leave this part to you to finish.

Answer (score 3):

You could write it as a series. If $n>0$, we can write
$$f(n,b) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty}\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{b^{k-1}}\right\rfloor\; mod\; b\right)$$
Where $a\; mod\; b$ is the remainder of the division $a/b$ and $\lfloor r \rfloor$ is the greatest integer not exceeding $r$ (also known as *floor* function)

Comment: i appreciate the effort but I was hoping for a short formula that i can use in coding ... where I don't have to use summation, is it even possible to make such a formula?

Comment: You could use it in coding, but insted of summing up to infinity you just sum up until $k$ is such that $\lfloor n/b^{k-1}\rfloor = 0$ - wich is equivalent to $b^{k-1}>n$

Comment: yeah i get what you are saying but i already am doing that but i need something to reduce the time complexity for very big numbers that's why i am trying to find a formula that could be used just by inputting n and B

Comment: @Animaniac:  this is a fine answer to the question as asked.  If you have further requirements on the function you should state them in the question.  What makes you think this is slow?  How large are the numbers you are thinking about?  Even $2^{1000}$ takes only $1000$ loops, so a few microseconds.

Comment: i edited the question ,sorry im new to this , hope this question now conveys what i want to ask

Comment: I *think* this is about as fast as you can get.  It literally *is* finding the digits and adding them.  I don't *think* there is any way to calculate the sum of the digits without calculating the digits themselves.

Comment: yeah i guess it doesnt get any faster ... then i would need the second part of the question to be calculated by some fast method

Comment: If $B,n$ are odd so is the output ... Just saying.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee ? can u elaborate

Comment: $$(2x+1)+(2y+1)=2(x+y+1)$$ $$2z+2a=2(z+a)$$  so only if there are an odd number of odd numbers will the sum not be even. That plus $$(2b+1)(2c+1)=2(2bc+b+c)+1$$ and $$(2d+1)(2f)=2(2df+f)$$ is enough to conclude in an odd base ( whose powers are all odd) odd digits create odd terms, and even digits create even terms, their sum parity follows from above.